# Android Studio error in POJO generator

Tags: java, android-studio, annotations

I have just downloaded, installed and tried a XML to POJO generator from Jet Brains here https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8113-pojo-generator

The problem is that, after the classes are generated I have a thousands of errors in the code, I think most of them come from annotations.

Piece of code here:

[image]

Is it anything else that needs to be configure in Android Studio for this to work and that is not mentioned in the page above?

Comment: have you added dependency for simple framework?

Comment: I have done nothing but install the plugin that i downloaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add dependency for `simple framework` as following in build.gradle file.

```
compile 'org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1'
```

For Android, you also have to exclude dependencies as they are already in the Android SDK

```
compile ('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
    exclude module: 'stax-api'
    exclude module: 'stax'
    exclude module: 'xpp3'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, im trying right now and will comment the results

Comment: yes solved, thanks...they should have added this info along with the plugin, I will accept the answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: okay. One observation: When you see Red error in import statements, always search for dependencies. Mostly adding dependencies solves the problems!

Comment: thanks!, I could have probably found the dependency myself....but that thing about "exclude"....that was a big help!